# Is there anyway to split posts to different databases?

Tags: database, performance

We have a huge database (4GB) and mostly are **wp_posts** wondering if is that possible to like, split it to two different databases to have better performance?

for example, split post types with PRODUCT to second database, and when client asks to fetch products, WordPress ask data from DB2 directly, not asking DB1 and redirect to DB2.

Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Better database keys may help. Here is a plugin for that. https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Answer (score 0):

that is a good solution, also woocommerce has plugins to create and move the products to custom table. this means instead a new database there is tables just for the products. also very efficient

Comment: what about custom posts? not products ( I know it is a custom post type ) what is that plugin? is that paid?